# IOS verify failed about External buy questiones

Tags: ios, external, verification

```
Reasons
11.13: Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected
```

11.13

We found that your app provides access to account registration. As this also provides the user access to mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, this is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Since the app includes access to services already purchased or subscribed by your existing users through means other than IAP, this is considered as a form of external mechanism.

Please see the attached screenshot/s for more information.

To be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines, it would be appropriate to remove access to account registration.

－－－－－

**The hotscreen is regist and login.**

**We had delete all links from App in 'about' ViewController.**

**And it just has a regist/login page in my App that is not have function of 'buy'.**

**But there is can pass with regist/login page in My other apps.**

My App is free app that is to show some video in iPhone.
The Video is also free in App that is not need to buy.
The user can regist a user to comment or favorite some video.
**I also have a web side for this. and user can buy some Charges Video in it.**

－－－－－

I hope someone can help me！！！

Answer (score 0):

I assume purchases are done at some external web-site of yours.
You cannot refer to Buy in your app, if purchases are not done via App store.

You have to look for alternatives, like use DB at your web-site for user purchases validation.
User can login and their purchased items shall be available for download.

You can have an information button or something which tells user to have a look at your web-site for more information/ "*you might also like*". 
Please note selling your stuff via App store shall be made on Apple inc terms only.
This do not restrict you to sell your stuff outside App store, but you cannot have selling links in your app.

You should not have user registration in your app, until you are using IAP.
This is stated in 11.12.

However I still feel you can have login in your app, and do registration /selling outside the app. This gives you liberty as your app is not selling content/neither doing any user registration.

I am having a couple of apps with my developer license and doing this i passed all validations of app submission both legally and review process as well.

Comment: This is confusing then, Let me summarise you are selling anything using your app, this is just having a login page, valid users then can see the list of items to be downloaded and used.

Have you verified for User registration in your app??
"What shall user registration will do in an app which do not uses app store purchases"?? Just check, i might be wrong in this. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks,i had deleted all links in my app.but i do not kown,why it is can not pass! and my app is free,please to see my qustion,i had fix it again

Comment: I have updated my answer, please review. You shall not be doing user registration as you are not using IAP (In-App Purchase).
Hope it was of any help to you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a registered user of yours can access stuff they bought on your website.
That is what apple is complaining about.

If you remove the login/register it will go through or use it just for commenting - maybe you can trick apple by renaming it to login-for-commenting/register-for-commenting (and for the time until it passed, disabling the "view-my-bought-stuff" from your website, so you can enable it without re-submitting the app)